# show/hide attachments

Tags: php, wp-query, media, get-posts, media-library

Is there a way to **show/hide** attachments in my case images on a post.

What I want is to mark an image as *"hidden"* and then only show it to the *admin* and hide hidden images from a normal user I know how to use `wp_query` and `get_posts` to get *attachments* also how to check if user is an *admin* just want to know if there is somewhere a  field or table where I can store a flag that the attachment is **hidden** or if there is any *"best practice"* for this.
Essentially I have an post with attached images and I display a gallery of the images on a page as a custom post type and I want is to show the “hidden” images to the admin but not to a user lower then admin. Atm. I am using:

```
$args = array(
'order'         => 'ASC',
'orderby'       => 'menu_order ID',
'post_type'     => 'attachment',
'post_parent'   => $post->ID,
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'post_status'   => null,
// Change the number of images to show in the gallery below
'numberposts'   => 999,
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
```

To retrieve the attachments

I tried  wp_delete_attachment witch confuses me because according to **WP documentation: ** `function wp_delete_attachment( $post_id, $force_delete = false )`  it has a parameter that does not permanently delete the attachment

> bool   $force_delete: Whether to bypass trash and force deletion.
>   Defaults to false.

but when I used it as: `wp_delete_attachment( $item,false );`

> `$item` being the id for the attachment

it deleted the image from the uploads folder. If the `wp_delete_attachment` function works as intended I would like to know how to query the deleted attachments that are bound to the post. So that the admin user has a chance to "restore" the image

Hope someone can help.

Comment: This is very confusing. Please clean up the grammar, punctuation, spelling, any relevant code, and try to explain the problem better.

Comment: Hope this clear's it up for you